# Jenkins - run 2 bat commando in parallel

Tags: jenkins

I have 2 applications (Putty and some diagnostic tool, lets call it "D") that I need to run i parallel to be able to log the traffic on a certain COM-port while the diagnostic tool is working.

My best tried for this is:

```
stage('Data collection') {
        parallel {

            stage('Start Putty') {
                agent {
                    label 'HCNJKENCFDSL'
                }
                steps {
                    dir("C:/..../PuTTY") {
                        bat 'putty.exe -load "myConfiguration"'
                    }
                }
            }

            stage('Start application') {
                agent {
                    label 'HCNJKENCFDSL'
                }
                steps {
                    bat 'C:/.../Application_D_Start.vbs'
                }
            }
        }
```

If I run this script this happens:

1. Application start
2. Putty starts
3. Application stops
4. Putty is going on forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
stage('Build') {
            steps {
                parallel(
                        Task1: {
                            sh 'echo task1 '
                        },
                        Task2: {
                            sh 'echo task2 '
                        }
                )
            }
```